# Multithreading my client Java program

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

I have a Java client (client server app) that does two main things: (1) listen to server to receive files and save them to a local folder and (2) watch that folder for changes and send changes to the server. I want to run each in its own thread. First, is it a good idea to run each task on a separate thread. Second, how do I lock the folder when it's used by either task to avoid interference?

Comment: Can you edit your post to show some of your work?  What have you tried?  What documentation have you read?

Comment: @Gray I'm not asking for code corrections; I'm seeking advice. How to lock a resource (folder in my case) and unlock it.

Comment: Small observation, if you want to lock the folder for single thread what is the point of having two threads ?

Comment: @Vash One thread can change files while they are being sent by the other or any kind of interference you can think of.

Comment: Is writing received file a change that must be send to a server? The server to load files from, and the server to send changes to - are they the same or different servers?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov No received files don't go back to server. There is only one server. It's like Dropbox, you have to keep files synchronized everywhere..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it a good idea to run each task on a separate thread

It sounds like a good idea to split your program into threads since the 2 tasks can work asynchronously and concurrently.  The 1st thread could be downloading at the same time the 2nd one is uploading.

> how do I lock the folder when it's used by either task to avoid interference?

I wouldn't do a lock at all.  I'd have your 1st thread read a file from the server, write it into the folder, and then add a `FileToSend` object (or maybe just a `File` object) to a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).  So instead of looking at the directory, your 2nd thread would just be waiting on the `BlockingQueue` for files to be sent to the server.  The [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) class should work well for this.  The `BlockingQueue` takes care of the locking for you.

If you *do* need to share a lock then you could just inject a lock object into your two threads:

```
private final Object folderLock = new Object();
...
new Thread(new Downloader(folderLock)).start();
new Thread(new Uploader(folderLock)).start();
...
```

A good pattern would be to define an `addFileToUpload(File fileToUpload)` method on your `Uploader` class.  Then your `Uploader` can decide what to do with it.  The `BlockingQueue` could then be local to the `Uploader`

```
Uploader uploader = new Uploader();
// pass the uploader into the downloader
new Thread(new Downloader(uploader)).start();
new Thread(uploader).start();
```

Comment: Great! Is BlockingQueue a Java class? How do I share it between the two threads?

Comment: Yes.  `BlockingQueue` is a Java interface.  `LinkedBlockingQueue` is one of the implementations.  You can define it outside and pass it into each thread `Runnable`.  See my lock example above.

Comment: Okay, so the downloader sends a `addFileToUpload` msg to the uploader but then the uploader is a member in the downloader, right? The downloader delegates uploading files to it. Or should I make that method a class method?

Comment: Yeah, I'd make it a member @saadtaame.  The class method would work but it's bad form IMHO.